# File not found error in xamarin android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

When trying to build the android project of the Xamarin solution. Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract doesn't exist anywhere on my system.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 
'Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for 
Android profile?
File name: 'Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.dll'
at 
Java. 
Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference 
reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.
Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver 
resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean 
topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver 
resolver)   project.Android
```

Comment: So did you check if the said DLL is referenced in your project?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see it anywhere. I tried adding a reference $(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd (or something like it), but nothing changed so I removed it.

Comment: Try delete the bin and obj folder and restart your VS.

Comment: Deleting the bin and obj folders didn't work either.